# Unable to access internet from Blackberry10 Simulator

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks

I am using Blackberry10 Simulator (BB10_2_0x.1521) and Couldn't connect to internet through simulator. I am using web services in my blackberry 10 application. Because of this issue I am not able to view my application in simulator even though it is getting installed successfully.

I referred some forums and tried changing from NAT to BRIDGED mode. This didn't help. I am working under a proxy internet connection. So I tried this thing... VM Player-> file -> Player Preferences -> Connection settings -> Manual Proxy Settings( here i have given the proxy details) . But of no use.

As a next option I tried using MDS services. As in forum they have mentioned to start MDS Connection Services before running the simulator. This also din help me.

I am using windows 7 system.

Please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use any web service in your application you have to add these lines in your 'config.xml' file.Otherwise you wont get permission to access those sites.Hope this helps :)

```
 <access uri="http://www.address1.com" subdomains="true">
    <feature id="blackberry.app" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
    <feature id="blackberry.invoke" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
  </access>
 <access uri="http://www.address2.com" subdomains="true">
    <feature id="blackberry.app" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
    <feature id="blackberry.invoke" required="true" version="1.0.0"/>
  </access>
```

Comment: How do you create Blackberry 10 apps? I am using html 5 webworks SDK....And which mode do you work with in the simulator? NAT or BRIDGED or CUSTOM ?? @Alfred

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it to Custom(VMNet#) and setting the custom one to NAT. That should allow you access.

I work in a proxy environment as well, and that's what I have to do. You may still have to enter proxy settings by the way.

Comment: can you be more precise?? please...You have specified to set it as custom -> VMNet# ....What is that "#"? i have VMNet0 to VMNet19. Which one I should select? and how to select the custom one to NAT??

Comment: You can set it to any number you choose. I chose 3, but any number should work as well